# NSTimer calls a function which uses block. This block calls method on self. (Retain cycle)

Tags: ios7, objective-c-blocks, nstimer

I am using NSTimer to call a function which refreshes table view data every second.
This function using block based AFNetworking calls to a web service. I am using __weak reference to NSTimer and self. 
Still self is not getting deallocated after view disappears. And this function is being called every second.

```
__weak NSTimer *timer;
 __weak id weakSelf = self;
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:weakSelf selector:@selector(loadData) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

...

```
- (void)loadData{
    MessageDataController *uDC = [MessageDataController new];

    __weak ChatViewController *weakSelf = self;

    [uDC messagesForUser:self.userID WithSuccess:^(NSArray *someMessages) {

            [weakSelf loadBubbleData];

    } failure:^(NSError *error) {

        [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:weakSelf.view animated:YES];
    }];
}
```

How can I implement this functionality. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see why you're using `weakSelf` here -- it doesn't appear that `self` is retaining the block

Comment: I tried to add breakpoint in `dealloc` method. I observe that when I press back button in navigation bar, `dealloc` is not called. If I remove the timer. Then `dealloc` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Invalidate your timer in the code that removes your view.

Comment: Its a view controller and it is removed by itself. Either by pressing back button of navigation bar or by swipe gesture of iOS 7

Comment: Seems like a good place to do it. viewDidMoveToSuperview or viewDidMoveToWindow perhaps? When either of those properties is nil in either method, you've moved out of the view hierarchy.